# Getting a list of network enabled processes

Tags: command-line, windows-xp

Can you possibly get a list of network enabled processes through command prompt that are working through internet and running on your operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netstat would probably do the trick - i'd suggest netstat -b or netstat -b -f (-b lists processes listening in or creating connections  -f mentions the FQDN of foreign hosts, if necessary.)

Comment: I don't have a -f option.

Comment: well -f  might be a newer option - tried it on a win7 system. -b should be good enough to tell you which processes are making or reciving connections,

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [netstat](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true) page in Microsoft documentation:

Displays active TCP connections and includes the process ID (PID) for each connection. You can find the application based on the PID on the Processes tab in Windows Task Manager

```
netstat -o
```

Comment: when i do it, -o only lists the pid. useful if you want to kill the task, but otherwise, -b is superior IMO

Comment: when was the -b option added? I am not positive that it exists in XP.

Comment: apparently it works on XP as far as i can remember,and i had someone online confirm it. i have no idea why MSDN didn't document that option